# Is there a way to force all child batch files launched from a parent to log into one single file?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

Suppose I am calling a parent batch file like this

```
call parent.bat >Log.txt
```

and within the parent.bat I calling other batch files which themselves call other bath files.

Now whats happening is, the batch files launched from within parent.bat, show their output on the console windows and do not log into Log.txt.

Is there a way to force all child batch files launched to log into Log.txt?

Answer (score 1):

Try "call file1.bat >> log.txt 2>&1"

The double arrow is important as it indicates append rather then overwrite the file - otherwise you will only get the result of the last file.   The 2>&1 redirects "STDERR" to "STDOUT"

Comment: I tried that. It didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

With a few experiment, I can't simulate your case. I just doubt if some of ur messages is stderr. If yes, then try
c:> call parent.bat >log.txt 2>&1